# Remove everything after the first whitespace in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

Here is the **dataframe:**

```
     State  RegionName            
0    NY     New York             
1    CA     Los Angeles      
2    IL     Chicago 865         
3    PA     Philadelphia Wrin   
4    AZ     Phoenix City
```

**I want the output to look like this:**

```
     State   RegionName           
0    NY      New             
1    CA      Los         
2    IL      Chicago            
3    PA      Philadelphia 
4    AZ      Phoenix
```

How to do it without using for loops ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`Series.str.split`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.split.html) with select first values by indexing:

```
print (df['RegionName'].str.split())
0             [New, York]
1          [Los, Angeles]
2          [Chicago, 865]
3    [Philadelphia, Wrin]
4         [Phoenix, City]
Name: RegionName, dtype: object

df['RegionName'] = df['RegionName'].str.split().str[0]
print (df)
  State    RegionName
0    NY           New
1    CA           Los
2    IL       Chicago
3    PA  Philadelphia
4    AZ       Phoeni
```

Comment: Can you explain why did you write `str[0]` after the `split()` function?

Comment: @Kakarot_7 - sure, if use `split` get lists from each value and need select first lists, so used `str[0]`

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternative using [`pd.Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html)

```
df['RegionName'] = df['RegionName'].str.extract(r'(.*)\s')
```

But my first instinct would be to use what [@jezrael](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62113481/12416453) mentioned.

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/TxSXN9/2)

Answer (score 0):

You could also `str.extract` the start of the string but exclude space `^[^\s]+` using regex

```
df['RegionName']=df['RegionName'].str.extract('(^[^\s]+)')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can replace extra words by `''` using [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html)

```
df["RegionName"] = df.RegionName.str.replace('\s.*','')
df
     RegionName state
0           New    NY
1           Los    CA
2       Chicago    IL
3  Philadelphia    PA
4       Phoenix    AZ
```